# understanding pytorch pycoco tools object detection output

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

I am using pytorch vision library for object detection. I am using utilities provided for objection detection metrics. https://github.com/pytorch/vision. I am seeing following output

`Epoch: [2]  [0/10]  eta: 0:00:50  lr: 0.000500  loss: 1.1589 (1.1589)  loss_classifier: 0.1807 (0.1807)  loss_box_reg: 0.0592 (0.0592)  loss_objectness: 0.6662 (0.6662)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2528 (0.2528)  time: 5.0786  data: 1.0029  max mem: 8476`

My question is what is numbers in the brackets denote? Another quesiton is what is difference between and loss and loss_classifier in this context. Kindly help me to understand output. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/a78d0d83d0a499fe8480d7a9f493676e746c4699/references/classification/utils.py#L20), it seems that the first value is the median value for the epoch and the second value in parentheses is the global average/mean. The difference between the value for `loss` and `loss_classifier` is that the value for `loss` is the sum of the losses of the individual parts (including that of the classifier, `0.1807 + 0.0592 + 0.6662 + 0.2528 = 1.1589`), whereas the value for `loss_classifier` is the loss for just the classifier of the model, i.e. the part that classifies the pixels into the different classes.

Comment: Thanks @Oxbowerce.